# Optimal SQL transaction lifespan

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I heard that transaction should be closed as fast as possible.

I have a legacy code which starts transaction and does a lot of work (going to cache, waiting for something and etc). I measured latency and it seems that sometimes it exceeds 500 ms. I heard that even 100 ms can cause problems with locking on hot handlers.

What transaction lifespan is appropriate for most projects? Is there a golden rule?

Comment: Locks and Transactions are different things that are commonly used together. Transactions must last for as much time as the job they enclose permits. Locks should be targeted to last for as little time as possible, however that may not be possible. Unless you run a system that handles a high number of transactions per minute, I doubt that a 500 ms transaction that includes locks would be a problem. What you should be asking is how common would transactions compete for the same records, and if it would be a problem that the second transaction needs to wait 500 ms when it happens.

Comment: Nope, there is no golden rule, it depends on your application's requirements. Therefore we cannot tell if 500ms long transactions will cause you a problem. Only you can check that. Lots of  lock wait timeouts are the indication that your transactions (and therefore row level locks held) are open for too long. Deadlocks are also an indicator, but that may result from bad design as well.